# Supermicro part number variations?

Tags: motherboard, supermicro

Is there a key to the suffixes used in Supermicro mainboard part numbers?  For example, Newegg sells a X10SL7-F**-O** but Supermicro's site only lists a X10SL7-F.

Comment: Did you ask Newegg what it means?

Comment: It did not occur to me that the sales support people would know anything about the items themselves.  They will not do pre-sales technical support, for example.

Comment: Typically when I have seen a vendor added suffix, it means the items were refurbished, new old stock, used or something of that nature. Those boards are not cheap, so you have every right to know what you are buying.

Comment: Ah! It might be Newegg's suffix for "open box".  I'll have to compare it carefully among different entries for "same" item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X10SL7-F-O is the retail package with box.

X10SL7-F-B is the bulk package.

> ### -O vs -B model numbers​
>
> Many people get confused with these model numbers when they can only
>   find an X10SL7-F-O, instead of an X10SL7-F, or an X10SLM+-F-B instead
>   of an X10SLM+-F. All model numbers are exactly as printed in their
>   respective sections. For real products, they get either an -O or a -B
>   appended to them, for retail or bulk packaging, respectively. An
>   example: A Supermicro X10SL7-F-O is a retail-packaged X10SL7-F
>   motherboard. A Supermicro X10SL7-F-B is a bulk-packaged X10SL7-F
>   motherboard.
>
> What's the difference between them? With retail packaging, you get a
>   box, with proper packaging materials. With bulk packaging, you get
>   something along the lines of an antistatic bag, a bit of protective
>   foam and some cardboard to wrap it all up.

Comment: You quote information but from where exactly?

Comment: That quote seems to be from [the FreeNAS forum](https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/so-you%E2%80%99ve-decided-to-buy-a-supermicro-x10-motherboard%E2%80%A6.25951/).